Отключить логирование пакета media_kit в Flutter
Я пишу веб-приложение на Flutter в Android Studio и использую пакет media_kit v1.1.11 для проигрывания видео. И все в этом пакете меня устраивает, кроме одного: он постоянно что-то пишет в логи.

Основная проблема в том, что эти логи пишутся в консоль в браузере (например Crome) даже после выпуска релизной версии.
Этого я не хочу.

Я изучал документацию к пакету media_kit: https://github.com/media-kit/media-kit. Но к сожалению так и не смог отыскать информации касаемо логов и как их отключить (не исключаю того, что там эта информация есть, но я ее не нашел в силу моих ограниченных знаний технического английского).
Имеется ли вообще возможность отключения логов пакета media_kit в консоль? Может хотя бы на релизной сборке?
Похожего вопроса где-то я не нашел.

Вот статья похожая на нужную вам - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75517857/how-to-disable-logging-in-easy-localization-package-in-flutter

@ЕвгенийЛи, да, благодарю, статья похожая. Только там решением проблемы стало отключение логирования путем методов самого пакета EasyLocalization. Конкретно же в моем случае, media_kit не предоставляет подобных методов (либо я их не нашел)

Так как там используется debugPrint, то по идее можно сделать так:
void main() {
  // Сохраняем оригинальную функцию debugPrint
  final originalDebugPrint = debugPrint;

  // Переопределяем debugPrint
  debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {
    if (message == null || message.startsWith('media_kit:')) return;

    originalDebugPrint(message, wrapWidth: wrapWidth);
  };

  runApp(MyApp());
}


Благодарю, этот вариант отлично сработал.
Да, media_kit использует debugPrint для логирования, причем без проверки константы kDebugMode, отсюда и логирование даже на релизной сборке.
В дополнение к вашему ответу, можно дописать условии проверку на kDebugMode, чтобы логирование данного пакета, сохранялось в режиме отладки.
